# Replacement of c++ fundamental type in large codebase

Tags: c++

The project has ~1M lines of code. Because the size of 'long' type is not specified strictly and depends on the architecture, there is a need to replace it with uint32_t/int32_t. It applies also to all the variations like unsigned long, signed long int etc:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

I'm looking for a suggestion how to find/replace them all and not spoil the comments, variable names.. Perhaps it can be smart regex or python mako script?

Comment: How many instances you get if you simply try to look for "long" with a wholewords flag on?

Comment: Seems like a task for clang libtooling to ensure proper identification.

Comment: @bracco23 Search of plain "long" gives ~7k hits.

Comment: To be more pedantic, as per standard, `uint32_t` and co. only exist if the underlying system supports them. `uint_least32_t` and co. on the other hand are fine.

Comment: why would you want to replace in code but not in comments? Contrived example, but you dont want something like `uint32_t x; // this is a variable of type long`, no?

Comment: You have a lot of work ahead of you if the code was written using proper Hungarian Notation.  This is a case I use against Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @user463035818 because I dont want comments like `//username too uint32_t`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Many would argue that repeating the type in the variable name is all but proper hungarian notation. The prefix should express additional meaning, not redundant information.

Answer (score 0):

You could risk a simple search and replace.

In the right order, it should work: `unsigned long long`, then `long long`, then `unsigned long`, then `long`, with regex features to consider the presence of `int` if you feel like.

Take into account that the only way to be sure of no mistakes is to use clang or another parser and parse the full code, which is a task way more difficult.

An example of the regex you could use in a search and replace editor that supports them are:

```
unsigned long long( int)?
(signed )?long long( int)?
unsigned long( int)?
(signed )?long( int)?
```